Merge two payload messages based on same value in both payloads
I am currently struggling with the merging of two payload messages.
I perform two http requests and receive a payload message back from both. Now I want to merge these two payloads using an identical value in both payloads.
Below are the two payloads marked with the identical value.


Maybe someone can give me some advice?
Thanks!

It would help if you could give us some insights on the language you're using and also feel free to dump the payload here in the question as a snipper so we can help you

The output of the http request arrears to be 2 arrays each with 2 objects. It's not clear from the question what output you would like, but I assume it's a single object with the name, location and weather data? This will need a multi stage process, a join node, then probably a function node

As mentioned in the comments, a join node and a function node can do this.

I'm using the 2 inject nodes to stand in for the http-request nodes, they both had topics set (location and sensors, it doesn't matter as long as they are different). They inject JSON arrays of similar form to that shown in the question.
The join node is set to manual to create an object using msg.topic as the key, and to send every input 2 messages

Finally the function node flattens the 2 arrays into a single object.
var newPayload = {}
for (const key in msg.payload) {
    for (const i of msg.payload[key]) {
        Object.assign(newPayload, i)
    }
}
msg.payload = newPayload
return msg

